# jQuery : Remove all occurences of pipe from input text fields

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML form with several inputs of type "text". If the user enters text into these inputs which contains the pipe symbol (|) I want to strip it out. Could you please share the jquery code on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How's about some sample input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace('|', '');
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! There was also no need to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
var value = $("#text").val(); //textbox ID

value = value.replace("|", ""); //this will give you the value without the pipes

$("#text").val(value); //put back in field if you want
```

Please see this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this is:

```
$('input:text').change(function() {
    $(this).val() = $(this).val().replace('|', '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion above, bind events to your text entry fields to trigger the character replacement.

```
$("input:text,textarea").blur(function(){
    //call the replacement function
});
```